# How to count in a column how many rows are left untill I get a specific value in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I'm a beginner with google sheets/exel formulas so i'm having trouble to count how many rows there are until I get a specific value, and this, multiple times in a same column.

Example bellow, I would like to set an ARRAYFORMULA in **B1** so I can get those results:

| Row\Column | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Value | Result |
| **2** | 0 | 1 |
| **3** | 1 | 0 |
| **4** | 0 | 1 |
| **5** | 1 | 0 |
| **6** | 0 | 4 |
| **7** | 0 | 3 |
| **8** | 0 | 2 |
| **9** | 0 | 1 |
| **10** | 1 | 0 |

The purpose is to count raws untill I get the value "1" in column **A** and put the result in column **B**:

So obviously I could use something like :

`B2=IF(A2=0;IF(ISNUMBER(B1);B1+1;1);0)`

And deploy this formula to every cells in the column **B**

But I really wish I could get an ARRAYFORMULA in **B1** to do so.

I tried to use:

`B1=ARRAYFORMULA({"Result";IF(A2:A=0; COUNTIFS(A2:A; 0; ROW(A2:A);"<="&ROW(A2:A)); 0)})`

But as you can presume, this won't work because A2 stay the value from where the count is done. Besides, the counting is reversed.

We would get something like , which is not what I want:

| Row\Column | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Value | Result |
| **2** | 0 | 1 |
| **3** | 1 | 0 |
| **4** | 0 | 2 |
| **5** | 1 | 0 |
| **6** | 0 | 3 |
| **7** | 0 | 4 |
| **8** | 0 | 5 |
| **9** | 0 | 6 |
| **10** | 1 | 0 |

I really struggle to increment values with arrayformulas so if anyone has done something similar, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Γ;index(A:A;index(match(2;1/(A:A<>""))));
   map(A2:Γ;lambda(Σ;if(Σ=1;0;xmatch(1;offset(Σ;1;):Γ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity, this works wonderfully.
Now, time to understand why !

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
=LET(val,A2:INDEX(A2:A,MATCH(9^9,A2:A)),
     REV,LAMBDA(arr,SORT(arr,SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),)),  
     REV(SCAN(,REV(val),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c,0,a+1)))))
```

It uses `SCAN` to do a resetting running count where both the input and output array are `REV`ersed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for sport, here you have an option that filters the row of the results and stacks decrementing sequences:

```
=LET(f,{0;FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A)),A2:A=1)},
REDUCE("RESULT",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(f)-1), LAMBDA(a,b,
{a;LET(d,INDEX(f,b+1)-INDEX(f,b), SEQUENCE(d,1,d-1,-1))})))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys! Lots of new keywords to get familiar with. I didn't know there was something like LAMBDA, this keyword seems to give much more opportunities to GS/XL!

Comment: LAMBDA and it's auxiliares (BYROW,BYCOL,REDUCE, SCAN,MAKEARRAY) are very powerful! And now you have LET since a couple of months ago, that allows you to have a logical order in naming variables and sequencing processes. Good luck!